# Integral $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1} \left( \tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1}(a-x) \right) dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

For $a\in\mathbb R$, I want to evaluate the integral
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1} \left( \tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1}(a-x) \right) dx.$$
I tried to integration by parts by considering $\left( \tan^{-1}(x) \right)' = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$, so that
$$I = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \tan^{-1}(x) \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{1+(x-a)^2}\right).$$
However, I cannot proceed further. Mathematica cannot solve both integrals.

How to evaluate $I$?

Comment: It may be worth differentiating $I$ as a function of $a$, or using contour integration

Comment: $\arctan a +  \arctan b = \arctan( (a+b)/(1-ab))$

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for your answer! Differentiation w.r.t. $a$ works!

Comment: @B.Goddard Thanks for your comment, but I am not sure how to proceed after that identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

In fact, the evaluation can be done by means of the complex integration method, and this evaluation is rather straightforward. Just one of the possible contours.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1} \left( \tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1}(a-x) \right) dx=I_1+I_2$$
It is evident that $I_1=0$ (the integrand is odd). As for $I_2$
$$I_2=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{(x+a)^2+1} dx$$
Using $1-ix=\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{-i\tan^{-1}x}\,\Rightarrow\,\ln(1-ix)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2)-i\tan^{-1}x\,\Rightarrow\,\boxed{\,\tan^{-1}x=-\Im\ln(1-ix)\,}$
$$I_2=\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln(1-ix)}{(x+a)^2+1} dx=\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\ln(1-ix)}{(x+a-i)(x+a+i)} dx$$
Switching to the complex integration and closing the contour by a big circle of radius $R\to\infty$ in the upper half-plane (counterclockwise), taking into consideration that $\ln(1-ix)$ does not have branch points inside the contour, and that there is a singe simple pole at $z=-a+i$
$$I_2=\Im\,2\pi i\underset{z=-a+i}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\ln(1-iz)}{(z+a-i)(z+a+i)}=\pi\,\Im\ln(2+ia)=\pi\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{2}$$
$$I=I_1+I_2=\pi\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

We proceed by FShrike's comment. We have
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \int \frac{1}{x^2+1} \frac{1}{(a-x)^2+1} dx = \frac{2\pi}{a^2+4}.$$
Since $I(a=0)=0$, we obtain
$$I(a) = \int_0^a \frac{2\pi}{a^2+4}da = \pi \tan^{-1}\frac a2.$$

Comment: I’m glad it helped. Ironically I now have to ask you: how did you obtain the middle identity? Is it a special $-\infty\to\infty$ contour integral or is there a nice antiderivative

Comment: @FShrike I don't know since I used Mathematica :)

Comment: Ironically, I think one can do that by contour integration (the method you proposed!).

Comment: I will post the derivation shortly, I have figured it out with contours